# Iterate over the neighborhood of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-time

### Input

A string S of length between 2 and 30. The only letters in the string will be `a` or `b`.

### Output

All strings within [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.) distance 2 of S. You must output all the strings without duplicates but in any order you like.

### Example

If `S = aaa` then the output would be (in any order):

```
aa
abab
ab
aabba
aaaa
abaa
bbaaa
aba
bbaa
babaa
bba
abaaa
abaab
baaa
baab
baaaa
baba
aabaa
ba
abba
aaba
aabb
abbaa
abb
aabab
aaaaa
aaaab
baaba
a
aaaba
aaabb
aaa
aab
ababa
aaab
bab
baa
baaab
```

### Constraints

Your code must be fast enough that it would run to completion on TIO when S is of length 30.  This is only to stop brute force solutions.

Comment: May we use any pair of printable characters instead of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Arnauld sure, why not.

Comment: Are you sure the constraint is enough to stop brute-force solutions? Length 20 gives about a million possible strings, and I can imagine a solution testing all of those within a minute on TIO.

Comment: The famous Swedidsh pop group `abba` is missing from your example output, and so are `baba`, `abaab`, `aabab` and `ababa`.

Comment: I think ```aaa``` has an edit distance of 1 with ```aa```.

Comment: @SunnyMoon My understanding is that _within_ implies \$\le2\$.

Comment: @Arnauld Hopefully all fixed now.

Comment: @xnor I will increase it to 30 as the existing solutions seem ok with that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>115</s> 109 bytes

- -6 thanks to Unrelated String

```hs
import Data.List
f=nub.(=<<)g.g
g=(=<<)h.(zip.inits<*>tails)
h(x,y)=[x++b++c|b<-["a","b",""],c<-[y,drop 1 y]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LboMwELz7K1YoUqA81KpXk0t77B9EHHbBASsOIOyoUPXfqb1uItnWzHhmdge0V2XMvuvbPC0OPtFh9aWtE5d6vFOV1lJmfdWLvmY4VOmPnis9amfly8mhNjYTQ7oWW1af1zynPG9/SZbnBJMiIX@Tpmg934pumWZ4g61p9hvqEWroJgGg1lm1TnUgS0itX6L6npbOZvJw6pX7mEanRme90SgH2Lo7Gh8NRjjABRJETKAsFzUb3aJT8P4KRzz6wLzoMZgeofo5a0cUSEgiHCTyDKOEwrMIGQl6iPwbXxIMnyi6QhND8d8YH2LKImvEs@JEjgdbYHELdnGQN4xa6Bex3LM/)

Explanation:

```hs
f :: String -> [String]
f=nub    -- delete duplicates
 .(=<<)g -- apply g to every result (get all words with distance <= 2)
 .g      -- apply g once to the input (get all words with distance <= 1)

g :: String -> [String]
g=(=<<)h               -- apply h to every split and flatten the resulting list
 .(zip.inits<*>tails)  -- split the string at every possible position

{- |
h takes a pair of Strings (x,y the input split at some point) and returns all
combinations of x, one of a, b or nothing, and y with the first letter present
or removed
("he","llo") -> ["heallo","healo","hebllo","heblo","hello","helo"]
drop 1 is basically the same as tail with the difference that drop 1 [] returns
[] instead of throwing an error
-}
h :: (String,String) -> [String]
h(x,y)=[x++b++c|b<-["a","b",""],c<-[y,drop 1 y]]
```

Comment: [-4](https://tio.run/##PU7LbsMgELzzFSsrUuzaRq16hVzaY/8g8mGxiYOCMTJEtav@u8ujiQRoZpiZ3Su6m9R639Vk58XDJ3qkX8p5cuHmLugEIx3JyCe40vJHWaqM8o69nDwq7SpyLddmq/h5rWtR1/2vYO25wKIpRLhF1/SBb82wzBbeYOs6MvGSM1btEyoDHIaZAMjVyt7LAVgLpQtr0O95GVzFDqdR@o/ZeGm8C0YtPWDv76hDNBrhABcoELGAtl2k1apHL@H9FY54DAG7KBNNjxB/ztoRCQoUJB4UIjDMEpLAMkyIiIeYfvMrSIJPlF2xKUHy35gfkWgSkybSrDwxxaMtsrxFcqVg2jBrsZ/k8sD@AA)

Comment: ...actually it's [-6 if you just get rid of `m` altogether](https://tio.run/##PU7LboMwELz7K1YoUqA81KpXk0t77B9EHHbBASsOIOyoUPXfqb1uItnWzHhmdge0V2XMvuvbPC0OPtFh9aWtE5d6vFOV1lJmfdWLvmY4VOmPnis9amfly8mhNjYTQ7oWW1af1zynPG9/SZbnBJMiIX@Tpmg934pumWZ4g61p9hvqEWroJgGg1lm1TnUgS0itX6L6npbOZvJw6pX7mEanRme90SgH2Lo7Gh8NRjjABRJETKAsFzUb3aJT8P4KRzz6wLzoMZgeofo5a0cUSEgiHCTyDKOEwrMIGQl6iPwbXxIMnyi6QhND8d8YH2LKImvEs@JEjgdbYHELdnGQN4xa6Bex3LM/)

Comment: I totally forgot you could do that. :O

Comment: Would you mind adding a little bit of explanation?

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
⊞υθ≔⟦θ⟧ηＦη«≔⟦⟧ζＦＬιＦabＦ³⊞ζ⭆ι⎇⁻ξκν…⁺λνμＦab⊞ζ⁺ικＦζ¿¬№υκ«⊞υκ¿⁼ιθ⊞ηκ»»υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY8xbsMwDEVn@xREJhJQp4yZAqNbUxhotqIDYziWEFWKZatoHOTsCq3a1STqfT2SjebQeLYp1XHQGBX0tCv3w2A6h5/9lwIt9dkHQE1wL4sVCZmEFBm9ta4bNRoiyPWGT5vluiXI5knBxxiM6w58RaPg2AbH4YYH4@KAvwoupMApqG6NbSvtr1hbAVYeBXyTnLXbn3215piZ//8HJgJzBnz3I1Y@unFeS3Cev1j3vMzxYs699pFtdvS0ePXCH@WjrGVqUdAuJWZOLz/2CQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υθ
```

Push the input to the predefined empty list as the first result.

```
≔⟦θ⟧ηＦη«
```

Start a breadth-first search using the input.

```
≔⟦⟧ζ
```

Start collecting potential new results.

```
ＦＬιＦabＦ³
```

Loop over each index, each potential insert/edit, and each operation (0=delete, 1=edit, 2=insert).

```
⊞ζ⭆ι⎇⁻ξκν…⁺λνμ
```

Apply the specified operation to the appropriate index of the current string.

```
Ｆab⊞ζ⁺ικ
```

Also consider appending either of `a` and `b` to the current string.

```
Ｆζ¿¬№υκ«
```

For each string that has not been seen before, ...

```
⊞υκ
```

... push it to the result string, ...

```
¿⁼ιθ⊞ηκ
```

... and if we're modifying the original input then also push it to the search space.

```
»»υ
```

Finally print all the results.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 113 bytes

Takes input as a singleton list containing the string.

```python
s="{k[:i]+c+k[i+w:]for k in %sfor i in range(len(k)+1)for c in['','a','b']for w in(0,1)}"
print eval(s%s%input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCsMgEIXhfU8hARnFLJouAz2JuJgG2w6GiahpKKVnt9rFg58PXnyX58aXWvN1@AQ7kzOLCZbMMbv7lkQQxELmntQzIT@8Wj2roM2kuy/NLcAI2HaD/@1ops7jpL/DKSbiIvwLV5VllsRxL0rrWi0gIrgf)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 114 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,d=2,i=0:d*s[i-1:]and{k[:i]+c+k[i+w:]for k in f(s,d-1)for c in['','a','b']for w in(0,1)}|f(s,d,i+1)or{s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BjoMwDEX3nMLqxjEEqTC7SOlFEIu0IR2LTqgSpKpiODtjmC4sW9/v2//5nr@n@LVtwT7cz9U7yNrbVrM9G1/mjuvG9C76ZewM99WtGjuuXqYPU4IROEJQYqgb2oWbCB2iRid1xQN6iabOuqH190A1Vw1NacnrlsECOofFM3GcZQlYX1BDntI8ePVpQQnjkEjDOLztY4hExcciw/6D9yDJxfugWg1tQ6YA@CfCaWHT@rWUTFBfYBH/cRJLJlohz4Ld84m2Pw)

**Commented**:

```python
f=lambda s,d=2,i=0:      # a recursive function with arguments:
                         #  - s, the input string
                         #  - d, the maximal Levensthein distance to s
                         #  - i, the index of the current operation
  d*s[i-1:]and ... or{s} # if d==0 or i>len(s) return a set containing s
                         # otherwise:
  {k[:i]+c+k[i+w:]       #  apply an operation
   for k in f(s,d-1)     #   on every string with maximal Levensthein distance d-1
   for c in['','a','b']  #   insert / replace with any of '', 'a', 'b'
   for w in(0,1)}        #   w==0: c=='': no operation, c!='': insertion
                         #   w==1: c=='': deletion,     c!='': replacement
  | f(s,d,i+1)           #  union this to the result of applying an operation at a larger index
```

Comment: Do you think this code can be made iterative? Just out of interest.

Comment: @Anush I originally had a iterative 116-byter but after reading your comment I found a shorter one ;). Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>137 134 131</s>  123 bytes

Expects a string with `0`/`1` instead of `a`/`b`. Returns an Object whose keys (and values) are the output strings.

```javascript
f=(s,k=2,o={},p='')=>[...o[s]=s].map((c,i)=>k&&[p+(q=s.slice(i+1)),p+(C=c^1)+q,(p+=c)+0+q,p+1+q,C+s].map(s=>f(s,k-1,o)))&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBta4MwEMff91McMjQh11TtnkuEUfZusA/gHE2zaG1dYo0MRvGzu1g2GH1xD/z5c7@728sv6VRXt/3c2A89jqUgDg8iRStOA7YiiqjIcs65zV0hXME/ZUuIwtrLhzDMW0aOwnHX1EqTmiWUopfWQr0nlB2RtEwoymLftizxec1@ZziRlRNqnqCllIahHVc5pAhLhGuEG4RbhDuEe4QHhCRGSH0sYyh4abtnqXbEgMjgNANQ1jjbaN7YimxetKn6HVydzADzzNfX7V6rnh/0tyMlCeKAd7rVsifGc3lztg/g@q42ldvQ1Wzw8X9k8GaemubPAR4PkZQyegwujJekOA484XzttKqbwI30j1rwRYWgJjGS2yhXhV9lNf4A)

#### Commented

This is a naive and rather lengthy implementation that just builds all the strings recursively.

```javascript
f = (                         // f is a recursive function taking:
  s,                          //   s = input string
  k = 2,                      //   k = counter
  o = {},                     //   o = an object used to store the results
  p = ''                      //   p = current prefix
) =>                          //
  [...o[s] = s]               // save s into o and split s
  .map((c, i) =>              // for each character c at position i in s:
    k &&                      //   abort if k = 0
    [                         //   otherwise, build an array:
      p +                     //     remove c by concatenating the prefix p
      (q = s.slice(i + 1)),   //     with the suffix q
      p + (C = c ^ 1) + q,    //     modify c
      (p += c) + 0 + q,       //     insert '0' after c (and update p)
      p + 1 + q,              //     insert '1' after c
      C + s                   //     prepend the modified c at the beginning
                              //     (this case is not covered by the insertions)
    ]                         //   end of array
    .map(s => f(s, k - 1, o)) //   do a recursive call for each string in there
  )                           // end of map()
  && o                        // return o
```

Comment: I don't know javascript but how does your code avoid duplicates?

Comment: @Anush It uses a dictionary as a set.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>115</s> 109 bytes

*Port of [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)'s answer in [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216310/83605)!*

```ruby
f=->s,d=2,i=0{d>0&&s[i-1]?['',?a,?b].product(f[s,d-1],[0,1]).map{_2[...i]+_1+"#{_2[i+_3..]}"}|f[s,d,i+1]:[s]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDoIwEEX3nGICiVUYJoWlCXABb9B0UUF0QlRCIUbbnh3RzX@L9/60nN/r2ld5bbGrSuRKuq6Wu51VnBe6UUJgY7A5axqnZ7e0875XW7o5VBILfaC7GZ1vccCXH5QkItZZm8WJGxRnL6ItDXHw/xtyVuijsjqsJS3j/NyX8gAOPPsIxmW2EJ8uj@t8g8RxgLze2CthRMqaLH8uIY5CFP3K/8BPGiM0pCAQxPoF)

TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves 3 bytes, and we've begin-less `...i` and end-less `i+_3..` ranges, which saves 3 more bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 89 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
nub.(g=<<).g
g(h:t)=t:((:)<$>"ab"<*>[h:t,t])++map(h:)(g t)
g _=["a","b"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDoMgEADAO6/YbDxAtTyAgKce@wNjmsVUJBUksv1@qdfJbFQ/731vLaZynAwPYtLPWFmsLn@9lsFZq3QQQW6GlWMjpVG2G5E82ts4XTrwrPo@UbmKkgFYiQAvNyHhgB7nlihmcFDOmBk6WAGJCNtvWXcKtd2XUv4)

The helper function `g` recursively generates all strings at Levenshtein distance 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://git.sr.ht/%7Engn/k), 78 bytes

```
{?"ab"@?,/e'e"b"=x}
e:{?,/(~+x==#x;{y,x,z}.',/0 1,/:\:(0,'!1+#x)_\:x;x_/:!#x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJw9T0EKgzAQvPsKuxaMGBq9ZhH7DxVNQKG0UBAPa0Xf3mA2XjKZ3cnMZNJbDcbCs5ZqTEewUNEejW4qlThyqqqEcFslyd/+SKUq4lIq3WpRyPRW5gllfasJqVf65sgeRYve7s16zHqKCYfvG8UwmdcHCVecs26PlgaMMYDCA1h7nq4EuiZ+dG14xcNT4u+n2PNAPLDPuWFgnbm8WemRM00wup5dHUKJ0CLYWI+cHuKDOf+HG4QobsSBDiUYyLo/+slwsQ==)