# Compute all close strings quickly

Tags: string, fastest-code

### Input

A string S of length between 10 and 16 inclusive. The characters are taken from the 95 printable ASCII characters, byte values `32` (`0x20`) to `126` (`0x7E`) (  to `~`)

### Output

Your code must compute and output all strings within [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.) distance 2 of S. You can have duplicates as long as you also have all the different strings and the output can be in any order.

### Scoring

I will generate a set of 5 strings of random lengths between 10 and 16, each consisting of a selection of printable ASCII characters. Each answer will be tested on the same set of strings, and your score is the total runtime over all 5, when run on my computer (spec details below). This means you need to give me simple and complete instructions on how to compile and run your code in Linux.

### Example

Input string `obenquillo`. Using my test code the first output string is `8benquifllo` and the last is `o^be9quillo`.  There are 1871386 different strings in the output.

### My PC

I have an AMD Ryzen 5 3400G running Ubuntu 20.04.

### Winning

The fastest code wins.

## League table

- My test Python code. 14.00s
- **C++** by the default. 0.15s. Bounty awarded.
- **C** by ngn. 0.07s
- **Python** by ReedsShorts sped up by ovs. 10.5s
- **Rust** by wizzwizz4 . 2.45s

Comment: @LuisMendo No, that's a code-golf question. This one is about speed.

Comment: [Closely related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216303/iterate-over-the-neighborhood-of-a-string) (code-golf, no duplicates allowed)

Comment: @LuisMendo I believe the rule is that if a reasonable attempt for one question would not be competitive for the other then they are not duplicates. Specifically, code-golf and fastest-code questions are unlikely to be duplicates.

Comment: For fastest code, you typically need to define computer architecture details, so people can optimize. Take a look at recent fastest-code challenges

Comment: @LuisMendo Details added. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend timing solutions over multiple strings of different lengths and using either the mean or the total time as people's score, otherwise people can ignore about lengths other than 10

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks. Edited following your suggestion.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this was posting in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), but if not, I'd suggest posting future questions there first for feedback before posting on the main site

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks. That's a good idea.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ignoring lengths other than 10 would be [optimizing for the given test cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2507/46076)

Comment: Does "within Levenshtein distance 2" mean the Levenshtein distance is at most 2 or exactly 2?

Comment: @wastl At most 2. Thanks for the question.

Comment: @xnoe the total RAM used for a long list of all the outputs shouldn’t be more than around 20MB  should it?

Comment: @Anush the point is since the only output required is the first and last string, the intermediate results do not matter. but yes, it will not hurt to just require the program to output them all

Comment: @ASCII-only Actually output them or just return them from a function?

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/310fae9b895cfb9bcbf71c388792a2c9) is a draft of an updated version of the question. The two main things I've changed are the testing set (expanded it to be 30 random strings) and the rules on the "correctness testing" (requiring answers to output all strings generated, which can be suppressed with `>/dev/null` when you test them). Feel free to use/modify/ignore this draft to better fit your view of the challenge, but I think this should address the issues pointed out in comments

Comment: Do the output strings have to also be in the same `0x20-0x7E` range?

Comment: @EasyasPi Yes that is right. There is an example in the question so you can check your code.

Comment: "You can have duplicates as long as you also have all the different strings and the output can be in any order" Can strings overlap? (I'm totally not trying to avoid having to handle character insertion) Are string separators necessary?

Comment: @thedefault. Yes string separators are needed.

Comment: Is GPU code allowed?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes! I mean I have no way to compareb it timewise but it would be great to have a GPU answer

Answer (score 11):

## C

```c
cat >a.c <<.
#define _(a...) {return({a;});}
#define F(i,x,n,a...) for(I i=(x),n_=(n);i<n_;i++){a;}
#define i(a...) F(i,0,a)
#define j(a...) F(j,0,a)
#define k(a...) F(k,0,a)
#define I(a...) F(i,a)
#define S static
#define O const
#define mc __builtin_memcpy
#define sl __builtin_strlen
typedef void V;typedef char C;typedef int I;

#include<sys/syscall.h>
#define M1(x) #x
#define M2(x) M1(x)
#define h(x,a...) ".globl "#x";"#x":"a"mov $"M2(SYS_##x)",%rax;syscall;ret;"
asm(".globl _start;_start:pop %rdi;mov %rsp,%rsi;call main;"h(write)h(exit));I write(I,C*,I);V exit(I);
V*memcpy(V*x,O V*y,I n)_(C*a=x;O C*b=y;i(n,a[i]=b[i])a)I strlen(O C*s)_(I r=0;while(*s++)r++;r)

S O C A0=32,A1=126+1,AN=A1-A0;S C o0[1<<20],*o=o0;
S V rpt(C*a,I n,I m){m*=n;while(2*n<m){mc(a+n,a,n);n+=n;}mc(a+n,a,m-n);}
S I fd(C*s,I n,I p)_(i(p,j(n,*o++=s[j+(i<=j)]))p)
S I fc(C*s,I n,I p)_(mc(o,s,n+1);rpt(o,n+1,p*AN);I(A0,A1,j(p,o[j]=i;o+=n+1))p)
S I fi(C*s,I n,I p)_(p++;i(p,j(n+2,o[i*(n+2)+j]=s[j-(i<j)]))rpt(o,p*(n+2),AN);I(A0,A1,j(p,o[j]=i;o+=n+2))p)
I main(I c,C**v)_(S C s[32];I n=sl(v[1]);mc(s,v[1],n);s[n]=10;S typeof(fd)*f[]={fd,fc,fi};
 i(3,o=o0;I g=f[i](s,n,n);j(g*(i?AN:1),C*b=o;k(3,f[k](o0+(n+i)*j,n+i-1,j%g))write(1,b,o-b);o=b))
 exit(0);0)
.
clang -O3 -march=native -nostdlib -ffreestanding a.c && strip a.out -R .comment
time ./a.out abcdefghijklmnop >/dev/null
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRdb6s4EH3nV1jJ9soGQyGV9qGOu4oircTDttJGirSKosh8BROwESa5RFV/e3ccctne@7APgD1nzszxzJhEmPLzMxU9ehFBipbLwJlneSFVjg5YBEFA0HuX9@dO4XfBPgj7mPA/saQDVXT0KnSHYyQ5HghVB44VYXKpDkx6HrHMiSbvYS09pIJMQDUB1c/AaQJOPwPxl1BfzBtketHLdDK8oVQr00/7JkWHQ3KWdS/VocmbtL1OmKm/YKbv6lw5/bXNAUYXLTO0ZT@2aSk6tJ62UvUoZo4zlyqtz1m@NFfzCE8q6jooX6YMf0VQIzQf/jMsrOFmnmwlHu6FnQXHWic1ms2HGbOv55mYNfqCfpsBcfPP5jCfD2RGHzoxsHs6Bi1jM0eYBv@gw1lE17Px89zqFj10mWQ20ENnWqAbySwXNUIqNivx9072OSlxPsieEBajmwHHdO3SmLAtsgCGlbN1xyLirTvQN7R1rzRGihzw2hV8YG9o7Sb8yiSGYdnJPU/gRQSJ0VhfbB0MuMeo4yH7Xso6x66Bwek8j3XEcTbQwjVahfxpQVcRjxa/exFdvfJV5K9CtgFMh7touVyEe@pqrkMGlC3q2t5KsGLgach743J1j79w1dJaUiw8kEVhXpUH6MdkaXxlx32DYlRkEMfc47SgVOKWVnAcV3seN7vKw3LJK7InpCUjI/2FAWE1NVR5EWFWl7ZL2rqrVygtXoVwLojYUr2r9lwyDVrAdQonfwnXQmXuIrwFkKRrF8QDMsjxQc5NzZipHUH6f7kWt1zxrfvQiBS67F4gkS2u2T0t9jAAipsaX3bRnjA4jqF2aQtndmrPI9sIexd0gYuMuMVuz9@LjBYpLeQHc@DiP9Fbb2J05AWMAERQll7ho4vlH6vX54hQOyqancC32J32WIceaJfEraBe0gfdD0dCxkmMaEK1nxCmeUKIM85jSFhInMBJa6GOyH97Qn4jurTkCn4Jlxz5Sps@q2WC/KLo8hzug8okuNrf37dvdiRlCxt97pH/NwpS3TS56p1eNjkKHkdAJCnc02Mpq1PdKLhLL49ZfnlU57r@/PwX)

for the record, here's why this answer didn't win the bounty: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56646474#56646474

Comment: Fast and incomprehensible :)

Comment: 0/10, not golfed enough. 

Comment: 6/9 needs lesser comments

Comment: For anyone reading this and thinking of adding their own answers, this question is not code-golf!

Answer (score 4):

## C++ ('C with operator overloading')

<sup>edit: no longer outputs any duplicates if the set of characters allowed for insertions and substitutions doesn't intersect with the string's character set! (further improvement will probably require something smarter)</sup>
<sup>edit2: now even less duplicates: doesn't consider cases like inserting `abcd` -> `abbcd` twice</sup>
<sup>edit3: tiny optimization in bufprint. I don't know how to optimize it further :(</sup>
<sup>edit4: optimized bufprint some more; edit5: found a better bufsize</sup>

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>

const char rStart = 32; //for testing purposes, I often set these to 48 and 49
const char rEnd = 126;
const bool enableio = true;
const int bufsize = 524288;
//char printbuf[bufsize];
int printbuf[bufsize / 32][8]; //using a size of 24 bytes per fixed-length string caused a SIMD unaligned store and was slightly slower
int printbufi = 0;
void bufflush()
{
    if(enableio) fwrite(printbuf, 32, printbufi, stdout);
    printbufi = 0;
}
void bufprint(const char* x) //not confusing because printbuf is the print buffer and bufprint prints using the buffer
{
    //most of the time is spent in this function
    if(printbufi >= bufsize/32 - 1)
        bufflush();
    __builtin_memcpy(&printbuf[printbufi], x, 20);
    //printbuf[printbufi][5] = 0x0a0a0a0a; //not necessary! it's possible to just set these newlines in the beginning and never change them again
    printbufi++;
    //bufflush();
}
struct string //not null-terminated
{
    char data[20] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    int len;
    bool operator < (const string& rhs) const
    {
        return memcmp(data, rhs.data, 24) < 0;
    }
    bool operator == (const string& rhs) const
    {
        const uint64_t* p1 = (const uint64_t*)this, *p2 = (const uint64_t*)&rhs;
        bool eq = p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1] && p1[2] == p2[2];
        return eq;
    }
    string insert(int i, char c) const
    {
        string copy;
        copy.len = len + 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            copy[j] = data[j];
        for(int j = i; j < len; j++)
            copy[j+1] = data[j];
        copy[i] = c;
        return copy;
    }
    string prepend(char c) const
    {
        string copy;
        copy.len = len + 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            copy[j+1] = data[j];
        copy[0] = c;
        return copy;
    }
    string pop_front() const
    {
        string copy;
        copy.len = len - 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < len-1; j++)
            copy[j] = data[j+1];
        return copy;
    }
    string erase(int i) const
    {
        string copy;
        copy.len = len - 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            copy[j] = data[j];
        for(int j = i; j < len; j++)
            copy[j] = data[j+1];
        return copy;
    }
    inline char& operator[](int i)
    {
        //if(i >= len) while(true) throw "abc";
        return data[i];
    }
    void print() const
    {
        bufprint(data);
    }
};
void changeloop(string x, int skip = -2) //all strings exactly 1 change away
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.len; i++)
    {
        if(i == skip || i == skip+1) continue;
        char oc = x[i];
        for(int nc = rStart; nc <= rEnd; nc++)
        {
            if(nc == oc) continue;
            x[i] = nc, x.print();
        }
        x[i] = oc;
    }
}
void changeloop2(string x, int skip = -2) //same with different skip
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.len; i++)
    {
        if(i == skip) continue;
        char oc = x[i];
        for(int nc = rStart; nc <= rEnd; nc++)
        {
            if(nc == oc) continue;
            x[i] = nc, x.print();
        }
        x[i] = oc;
    }
}
void insertloop(string x, int max = INT_MAX) //all strings exactly 1 insertion away
{
    //example:
    //?abcd
    //a?bcd
    //ab?cd
    //abc?d
    //abcd?
    //it can be observed that each character simply iterates over all possible values, and then gets set to the ith character of the string
    string s = x.prepend(x[0]);
    max = std::min(max, s.len);
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        for(char nc = rStart; nc <= rEnd; nc++)
        {
            if(i != 0 && x[i-1] == nc) continue;
            s[i] = nc, s.print();
        }
        if(i < x.len) s[i] = x[i];
    }
}
void deleteloop(string x, int max = INT_MAX)
{
    //example:
    //bcde
    //acde
    //abde
    //abce
    //abcd
    //erase first character, print and then copy the original character n-1 times
    string s = x.pop_front();
    s.print();
    max = std::min(max, x.len - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        s[i] = x[i];
        s.print();
    }
}
void dist1(string x)
{
    x.print();
    changeloop(x);
    insertloop(x);
    deleteloop(x);
}
//options:
//insert
//insert, change
//insert, insert
//change
//change, change
//delete
//strings with distance at most 1 from delete
void dist2(string x)
{
    string s = x.prepend(x[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < x.len+1; i++)
    {
        for(char nc = rStart; nc <= rEnd; nc++)
        {
            //string s = x.insert(i, nc);
            if(i != s.len-1 && s[i+1] == nc) continue;
            s[i] = nc;
            //s[s.len] = 0;
            s.print(); //insert
            insertloop(s, i+1); //insert, insert. only do the second insert before this one
            changeloop(s, i); //insert, change. the change can be anywhere except i and i+1
        }
        if(i < x.len) s[i] = x[i];
    }
    //changeloop(x); //change. can always be replaced by delete->reinsert
    for(int i = 0; i < x.len; i++)
    for(int j = i+1; j < x.len; j++)
    {
        char oci = x[i], ocj = x[j];
        for(int nci = rStart; nci <= rEnd; nci++)
        for(int ncj = rStart; ncj <= rEnd; ncj++)
        {
            if(nci == oci) continue;
            if(ncj == ocj) continue;
            x[i] = nci; x[j] = ncj;
            x.print(); //change, change
        }
        x[i] = oci; x[j] = ocj;
    }
    s = x.pop_front();
    s.print();
    changeloop(s);
    insertloop(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < x.len-1; i++)
    {
        s[i] = x[i];
        //s[s.len] = 0;
        s.print();
        changeloop2(s, i);
        insertloop(s);
        deleteloop(s, i); //deletion must be before i
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("input the string as a command line argument! :(\n");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(printbuf, 0x0a, sizeof(printbuf));
    string s; strcpy(s.data, argv[1]); s.len = strlen(argv[1]);
    s.data[s.len] = 10; //fix the null byte that should not be there
    //for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    //{
    //  dist2(s);
    //  fprintf(stderr, "%d\r", i);
    //}
    dist2(s);
    bufflush();
}
```

This outputs many empty lines between strings (to avoid unaligned memory writes to the IO buffer).
This outputs much fewer duplicates than the C answer: for `abcdefghijklmnop` the C answer outputs 10237362 lines, and my answer outputs only <s>4920334</s> <s>4774446</s> 4724312 non-empty lines, while only 4720038 are necessary.
I compile with `g++ a.cpp -std=c++17 -march=native -Ofast -no-pie -fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: Could you say something about how it works ?

Comment: @Anush I thought reading the code would be sufficient to understand how it works, but it simply tries making at most 2 modifications to the string and prints all the results. It also skips many modifications that are likely to produce duplicate results (for example, `changeloop(x);` in `dist2` is commented out because, as the comment says, it can always be replaced by a deletion followed by inserting the modified character, and insertions are not attempted after substitutions because it's always sufficient to perform substitutions after insertions and normal insertions).

Comment: I really like the way you have avoided duplicates. I will time this and others as soon as possible.

Comment: Imma turn it to CUDA and see how fast it can be

Comment: @CommandMaster This program's execution speed is currently bound by writing the strings to the IO buffer, and it outputs at around 2.5 GIB/s, so I don't think it will be any faster.

Comment: @thedefault. oh. So the main slowdown is in print()? GNU's `yes` can print ~7GiB/s on my computer, maybe you can copy some stuff from it?

Comment: @CommandMaster I tried puts and it outputs at around 850 MiB/s (there's a small optimization, but it probably won't push it above 900 MiB/s). Indeed, I should probably read the `yes` source code and the answers to Fastest yes in the west.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3

```bash
cat >a.py <<.
strs=[input()]
def a(b):
    new = []
    for x in range(32, 127):
        c = chr(x)
        for strn in b:
            for y in range(0, len(strn)):
                start = strn[:y]
                end = strn[y+1:]
                new.append(start + c + end)
                new.append(start + end)
                new.append(start + c + strn[y:])
            new.append(strn + c)
    return new
print(len(a(set(a(strs)))))
.
time python3 a.py <<<abcdefghijklmnop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwDIbveQofExVVAw6TqsKLVD2kJdBs4EaJ0cjTd/YKQxUX/kMkx9/vOHZn0zBNvSXY2zJkqOtSJYpp13gMV9KmVQd3BKs7UylgofuBHTTtX3AcI9zAI0SLJ6e3mxWsN593UtQz2w9R38z/lXj4BRRb9yQfqfws97GCs0MtsDFLUpTIRuL6km@q3L4ADg@PdC7W1SvAfyltCMzpuVjBDRfiM@@w73JSc@6iapeGBcwjYXYGoqMrx5xXIXokLYOwOjmSk/djRKpU5C8OQqZhxC3cN1jbruelnQb/9X2@4Bim6Rc)

Optimized by ovs, thanks.

Comment: Converting between strings and lists is quite slow, using string slicing and some minor optimizations, this gets [twice as fast](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwDIbveQofExVVAw6TqsKLVD2kJdBs4EaJ0cjTd/YKQxUX/kMkx9/vOHZn0zBNvSXY2zJkqOtSJYpp13gMV9KmVQd3BKs7UylgofuBHTTtX3AcI9zAI0SLJ6e3mxWsN593UtQz2w9R38z/lXj4BRRb9yQfqfws97GCs0MtsDFLUpTIRuL6km@q3L4ADg@PdC7W1SvAfyltCMzpuVjBDRfiM@@w73JSc@6iapeGBcwjYXYGoqMrx5xXIXokLYOwOjmSk/djRKpU5C8OQqZhxC3cN1jbruelnQb/9X2@4Bim6Rc).

Answer (score 3):

## Rust

Tested with `rustc 1.51.0-nightly (e22670468 2020-12-30)`.
Must be compiled with `-O1` (or above) so functions are properly inlined, or it segfaults.

Please build with `cargo build`, then time the binary in `target/debug/q216902`. It's segfaulting in release mode at the moment, and I don't know why.

### `Cargo.toml`

```rust
[package]
name = "q216902"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["wizzwizz4"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rlibc = "1.0.0"

[profile.dev]
debug-assertions = true
opt-level = 1
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
# debug = 2
```

### `main.rs`

```rust
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(const_in_array_repeat_expressions)]
#![feature(const_maybe_uninit_assume_init)]
#![feature(link_args)]
#![feature(naked_functions)]
#![feature(test)]
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

#[allow(unused_attributes)]
#[link_args = "-nostartfiles"]
extern "C" {}

extern crate rlibc;

use core::convert::TryInto;
use core::hint::{black_box, spin_loop, unreachable_unchecked};
use core::panic::PanicInfo;
use core::ptr;
use core::slice;
use core::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, fence, Ordering};
use core::mem::MaybeUninit;

static PRINTABLES: [u8; 95] = *b" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\
                                  @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_\
                                  `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
const FRAMECOUNT: usize = 4;
static mut FRAMES: [Frame; FRAMECOUNT] = [
    unsafe { MaybeUninit::<Frame>::uninit().assume_init() }; FRAMECOUNT
];

static FRAMELENS: [AtomicUsize; FRAMECOUNT] = [
    AtomicUsize::new(0); FRAMECOUNT
];

#[repr(C)]
struct iovec {
    iov_base: *const u8,
    iov_len: usize
}

const FRAMESIZE: usize = 256;
#[repr(C)]
struct Frame {
    iovecs: [MaybeUninit<iovec>; FRAMESIZE]
}

#[no_mangle]
#[naked]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    // Escape naked without clobbering stack pointer
    // https://fasterthanli.me/series/making-our-own-executable-packer/part-12
    asm!(
        "mov rdi, rsp",
        "call main",
        options(noreturn)
    );
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn main(stack: *const u8) -> ! {
    let input: &'static [u8] = unsafe {
        let arg1 = *stack.offset(16).cast();
        slice::from_raw_parts(arg1, cstr_strlen_cheat(arg1))
    };
    unsafe {
        spawn_printer();
    }

    let mut frame_i = 0;
    let mut frame_j = 0;
    let mut frame = unsafe { get_frame(0) };

    macro_rules! main_write {
        (@iovec $iov: expr) => {{
            frame.iovecs[frame_j] = MaybeUninit::new($iov);
            frame_j += 1;
            if frame_j > FRAMESIZE {
                unsafe { unreachable_unchecked(); }
            }
            if frame_j == FRAMESIZE {
                unsafe { write_frame(frame, frame_i, FRAMESIZE); }
                frame_j = 0;
                frame_i += 1;
                frame_i %= FRAMECOUNT;
                frame = unsafe { get_frame(frame_i) };
            }
        }};

        (@single $slice: expr) => {{
            main_write!(
                @iovec
                iovec {
                    iov_base: &$slice[0],
                    iov_len: $slice.len()
                }
            );
        }};

        ($($x: expr),*) => {{
            $(
                main_write!(@single $x);
            )*
        }};
    }

    macro_rules! main_writeln {
        ($($x: tt)*) => {{
            main_write!($($x)*);
            main_write!(b"\n");
        }};
    }

    ///////////
    // No-op ///
    //   No-op
    // Insert //
    //   I.
    //   .I.
    //   .I
    // Delete /////////
    //   Predel
    //   Delete
    //   Appdel
    // Insert insert //
    //   II.
    //   I.I.
    //   I.I
    //   .II.
    //   .I.I.
    //   Insert append
    //   Append append
    // Insert delete ////// (also includes Substitute)
    //   Prepend predel
    //   Prepend delete
    //   I.D
    //   Insert predel
    //   Insert delete
    //     .I.D.
    //     .S.
    //     .D.I.
    //   Insert appdel
    //   D.I
    //   Append delete
    //   .S
    // Insert substitute //////
    //   IS.
    //   I.S.
    //   Prepend substappend
    //   S.I.
    //   .SI.
    //   .S.I.
    //   Insert substitute
    //   .I.S
    //   Subsprepend append
    //   .S.I
    //   .SI
    // Substitute substitute //
    //   SS.
    //   .SS.
    //   .SS
    //   S.S
    //   S.S.
    //   .S.S.
    //   .S.S
    // Delete delete //////////
    //   Del2 XX.
    //   Del2 .XX.
    //   Del2 .XX
    //   Del2 X.X
    //   Del2 X.X.
    //   Del2 .X.X.
    //   Del2 .X.X
    // Delete substitute //
    //   DS.
    //   .DS.
    //   .DS
    //   D.S
    //   S.D
    //   D.S.
    //   S.D.
    //   .D.S.
    //   .S.D.
    //   .D.S
    //   .S.D
    ///////////////////////

    let len = input.len();

    main_writeln!(input);  // No-op
    main_writeln!(input[1..]);  // Predel
    main_writeln!(input[2..]);  // Del2 XX.
    main_writeln!(input[.. len-1]);  // Appdel
    main_writeln!(input[.. len-2]);  // Del2 .XX
    main_writeln!(input[1 .. len-1]);  // Del2 X.X

    for i in 1 .. len-1 {
        main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i + 1..]);  // Delete
    }

    for i in 1 .. len-2 {
        main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+2 ..]);  // Del2 .XX.
        main_writeln!(input[1 .. i+1], input[i+2 ..]);  // Del2 X.X.
        main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 .. len-1]); // Del2 .X.X

        for j in i+2 .. len-1 {
            // Del2 .X.X.
            main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 .. j], input[j+1 ..]);
        }
    }

    for ai in 0..PRINTABLES.len() {
        let a = &PRINTABLES[ai .. ai+1];

        main_writeln!(a, input);  // I.
        main_writeln!(input, a);  // .I

        for i in 1..len {
            main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i..]);  // .I.
        }

        for bi in 0..PRINTABLES.len() {
            let b = &PRINTABLES[bi..bi + 1];

            main_writeln!(a, b, input);  // II.
            main_writeln!(a, b, input[1..]);  // IS.
            main_writeln!(a, b, input[2..]);  // SS.
            main_writeln!(a, input, b);  // I.I
            main_writeln!(a, input[.. len-1], b);  // Prepend substappend
            main_writeln!(a, input[1 ..], b); // Subsprepend append
            main_writeln!(a, input[1 .. len-1], b); // S.S
            main_writeln!(input, a, b);  // Append append
            main_writeln!(input[.. len-1], a, b);  // .SI
            main_writeln!(input[.. len-2], a, b);  // .SS
            
            for i in 1..len {
                main_writeln!(a, input[..i], b, input[i..]);  // I.I.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i..], b);  // Insert append
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, b, input[i..]);  // .II.
            }

            for i in 1 .. len-1 {
                main_writeln!(a, input[..i], b, input[i+1 ..]);  // I.S.
                main_writeln!(a, input[1 .. i+1], b, input[i+1 ..]); // S.I.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i .. len-1], b); // .I.S
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, b, input[i+1..]);  // .SI.

                for j in i+1 .. len {
                    // .I.I.
                    main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i..j], b, input[j..]);
                }

                for j in i+2 .. len {
                    // .S.I.
                    main_writeln!(
                        input[..i], a, input[i+1 .. j], b, input[j..]
                    );
                }

                for j in i+2 .. len-1 {
                    // .S.S.
                    main_writeln!(
                        input[..i], a, input[i+1 .. j], b, input[j+1 ..]
                    );
                }

                for j in 1..i {
                    // Insert substitute
                    main_writeln!(input[..j], a, input[j..i], b, input[i+1..]);
                }

                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+1 ..], b);  // .S.I
            }

            for i in 1 .. len-2 {
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, b, input[i+2 ..]);  // .SS.
                main_writeln!(a, input[1 .. i+1], b, input[i+2 ..]);  // S.S.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+1 .. len-1], b);  // .S.S
            }
        }

        main_writeln!(a, input[1..]);  // Prepend predel
        main_writeln!(a, input[2..]);  // DS.
        main_writeln!(a, input[.. len-1]);  // I.D
        main_writeln!(a, input[1 .. len-1]);  // S.D
        main_writeln!(input[1..], a);  // D.I
        main_writeln!(input[1 .. len-1], a);  // D.S
        main_writeln!(input[.. len-1], a);  // .S
        main_writeln!(input[.. len-2], a);  // .DS

        for i in 1..input.len() - 1 {
            main_writeln!(a, input[..i], input[i+1 ..]);  // Prepend delete
            main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 ..], a);  // Append delete
            main_writeln!(input[1 .. i+1], a, input[i+1 ..]); // Insert predel
            main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i .. len-1]);  // Insert appdel
            main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+1 ..]);  // .S.

            for j in 1..i {
                // .I.D.
                main_writeln!(input[..j], a, input[j..i], input[i+1 ..]);
            }

            for j in i+2..len {
                // .D.I.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 .. j], a, input[j..]);
            }
        }

        for i in 1 .. len-2 {
            main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+2 ..]);  // .DS.
            main_writeln!(input[1 .. i+1], a, input[i+2 ..]);  // D.S.
            main_writeln!(a, input[1 .. i+1], input[i+2 ..]);  // S.D.
            main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 .. len-1], a);  // .D.S
            main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+1 .. len-1]); // .S.D

            for j in i+2 .. len-1 {
                // .D.S.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], input[i+1 .. j], a, input[j+1 ..]);

                // .S.D.
                main_writeln!(input[..i], a, input[i+1 .. j], input[j+1 ..]);
            }
        }
    }

    unsafe { write_frame(frame, frame_i, frame_j); }

    while FRAMELENS[frame_i].load(Ordering::SeqCst) > 0 {
        sched_yield();
    }
    unsafe { exit_group(0); }
}

/// strlen, if the string's length is >= 10 and <= 16.
#[inline]
unsafe fn cstr_strlen_cheat(ptr: *const u8) -> usize {
    for i in 10..=16 {
        if *ptr.offset(i) == 0 {
            match i.try_into() {
                Ok::<usize, _>(i) => return i,
                Err(_) => unreachable_unchecked()
            }
        }
    }
    unreachable_unchecked();
}

/// Gets a frame for writing, assuming nobody else has it.
#[inline]
unsafe fn get_frame(i: usize) -> &'static mut Frame {
    loop {
        let count = FRAMELENS[i].load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        if count == 0 {
            break;
        }
        sched_yield();
    }
    &mut FRAMES[i]
}

#[inline]
unsafe fn write_frame(_frame: &'static mut Frame, i: usize, count: usize) {
    FRAMELENS[i].store(count, Ordering::SeqCst);
}

#[inline(never)]  // for correctness
unsafe extern "C" fn spawn_printer() {
    let stack_pointer: *const u8;
    asm!(
        "mov {0}, rsp",
        out(reg) stack_pointer
    );
    let new_stack = stack_pointer.offset(-0x1000);
    let spawn_addr = (new_stack as *mut (extern "C" fn() -> !)).offset(1);
    ptr::write(spawn_addr, printer);
    clone(new_stack)
}

extern "C" fn printer() -> ! {
    loop {
        for i in 0..FRAMECOUNT {
            let mut count;
            loop {
                count = FRAMELENS[i].load(Ordering::SeqCst);
                if count > 0 {
                    break;
                }
                // sched_yield();
            }
            fence(Ordering::SeqCst);
            unsafe {
                writev((&FRAMES[i].iovecs[0]).as_ptr().cast(), count);
            }
            FRAMELENS[i].store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
        }
    }
}

// https://thevivekpandey.github.io/posts/2017-09-25-linux-system-calls.html
#[inline]
unsafe fn writev(iovecs: *const iovec, count: usize) {
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") 20,
        in("rdi") 1,
        in("rsi") iovecs,
        in("rdx") count,
        options(nostack)
    );
}

#[inline]
fn exit(code: i32) -> ! {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "syscall",
            in("rax") 60,
            in("rdi") code,
            options(nostack, noreturn)
        );
    }
}

#[inline]
unsafe fn exit_group(code: i32) -> ! {
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") 231,
        in("rdi") code,
        options(nostack, noreturn)
    );
}

#[inline]
unsafe fn just_exit() -> ! {
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") 231,
        options(nostack, noreturn)
    )
}

#[inline]
fn sched_yield() {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "syscall",
            in("rax") 24,
            options(nostack)
        )
    }
}

/// Wait for signal.
#[inline]
fn pause() {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "syscall",
            in("rax") 34,
            options(nostack)
        )
    }
}

#[inline(always)]  // for correctness
unsafe fn clone(new_stack: *const u8) {
    const CLONE_FILES: u64 = 0x400;  // Keep stdout as fd 1
    const CLONE_FS: u64 = 0x200;
    const CLONE_IO: u64 = 0x80000000;  // I/O scheduling efficiency
    const CLONE_PARENT: u64 = 0x8000;
    const CLONE_SIGHAND: u64 = 0x800;
    const CLONE_THREAD: u64 = 0x10000;  // Same thread group
    const CLONE_VM: u64 = 0x100;  // Same memory map
    
    const flags: u64 = CLONE_FILES | CLONE_IO
                       | CLONE_VM
                       | CLONE_THREAD
                       | CLONE_FS | CLONE_PARENT | CLONE_SIGHAND;
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") 56,
        in("rdi") flags,
        in("rsi") new_stack,
        options(nostack)
    );
    return;
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    unsafe {
        if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            // just_exit();
        }
        // unreachable_unchecked();
        asm!(
            "ud2",
            options(nostack, noreturn)
        )
    }
}
```

This is cleaner code; I'm making a better version, hopefully less segfaulty in release mode. I also haven't tweaked the `FRAMECOUNT` and `FRAMESIZE` parameters for optimal speed.